# iOS4 accessing the DCIM folder

Tags: xcode, permissions, ios4

I would like to read/write to the DCIM folder.

I was able to perform this operation under 3.1.3, but it fails under 4.0. Has the actual location been moved within the iPod directory tree?

Previously it was located at:

```
/var/mobile/Media/DCIM
```

I do not have a jailbroken 4.0 machine, so I cannot find the true location of the DCIM folder.

Did apple close the exploit of being able to write to the location from any application, or did they move it to another location??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was [removed for security reasons](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2010-1751).

It allowed apps to see your GPS location from photos in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

To be straight, now there is virtually NO way to access the user's photos apart from the UIImagePickerController? Even if I don't want to submit an app featuring these functions to the AppStore?

I can read out all of the thumbnails on my iPhone 4, but not the DCIM...